# MongoDB. Sort and Filter data

Tags: mongodb, sorting, filter

I have two collections in database - "products" and "category".

Each product have relation to categories, may inherit products of children categories for example:

Collection "category" (category tree):

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Category 1", 
    "parent": None,
    "inherit": true, ...
}

{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Subcategory 1", 
    "parent": "1", ...
}, ...
```

Collection "product":

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Product",
    "categories": ["2"],
    "price": 1000, ...
}, ...
```

I create a pages with filters of product by categories, prices and other properties and I realised sort of results by fields "name", "price" like that:

```
products.find({"categories": {"$in": ["1", "2"]}, "price": {"$gte": 1000, "$lte": 5000}}).sort({"price": -1})
```

Now, I need to manually set product's order for each category. 
How can I do that?

Also, category may have more than 10000 products, but after filtering I want, that order of filtered products will stay as it's been before filtering, only without products that doesn't match filter conditions.

---

I think I need something like this, but i'm not sure:
    products.find({"categories": {"$in": ["1", "2"]}, "price": {"$gte": 1000, "$lte": 5000}}).sort({"category_order.1": 1})

and in each product add dict {"category_order": {"1": 1, "2": 1}}, where keys is category_id, and value is order in category.

Any ideas?